# What lasts longer under the elements: polyester rope or galvanized wire?

Tags: weather-resistant

We live in the Caribbean, so we get tons sun, extremely hot days (at least 85F during these weeks), and lots of rain. We also live next to the ocean, so there's rust everywhere.

If I were to place a stretched piece of 1/4" galvanized wire and a stretched piece  of 3/8" polyester rope in my rooftop, which would last longer under these elements?

I understand the galvanized rope is stronger; my concern is the rust. Anything made out of iron will have signs of rust in two weeks.

Comment: Stainless steel rope will last the longest and is pretty impervious to nature.

Comment: Is stainless steel more or less the same price as galvanized steel?

Comment: Stainless steel is more expensive, but it lasts practically forever, doesn't rust, and doesn't need maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Galvanized rope won't rust quickly at all the galvinization prevents rust from forming. Do you see any chain link fencing in your area it is similar but a larger wire size than the strands in 1/4 rope but this could provide an idea. Poly rope will break down from the UV light in sunlight it starts to "chalk" at first then the outer strands start breaking leaving sharp little wiskers. I hang electrical wires on galvanized rope all the time but would never use any kind of other rope as it won't last as long as the galvanized. Note if after you assemble your clamps you have scratched the wire you can use a Zink rich paint or a spray can of cold galvanizing spray paint on the hardware and it will outlast almost anything.

Comment: I use nylon rope to secure a fence gate in my yard.  It's supposedly more weather resistant that poly rope, but I still have to replace it every couple of years.  I'd definitely go with the galvanized wire if you want longevity.